# Excel Write is not working when first column of the row is empty

Tags: java, excel, selenium, selenium-webdriver

when the first column of the row is empty, excel write is not working. second and remaining column values also checking if the first column is filled or empty. any reason behind or how to over come this issue.

**Test1: first column empty**

```
        package DataDrivern;

        import java.io.File;
        import java.io.FileInputStream;
        import java.io.FileOutputStream;

        import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
        import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

        public class ExcelWrite {

            public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
            {

                File src=new File("D:\\Selenium Learning\\input.xlsx");
                FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(src);
                XSSFWorkbook wb=new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
                XSSFSheet ws=wb.getSheet("Sheet2");

                System.out.println("excel read successfully");

                ws.getRow(0).createCell(0).setCellValue("test");

                FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(src);
                wb.write(fos);
                wb.close();


            }

        }
```

[image]

**Output**

```
        excel read successfully
        Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
            at DataDrivern.ExcelWrite.main(ExcelWrite.java:22)
```

**Test 2: first column not empty**

before running code:
[image]

```
        package DataDrivern;

        import java.io.File;
        import java.io.FileInputStream;
        import java.io.FileOutputStream;

        import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
        import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

        public class ExcelWrite {

            public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
            {

                File src=new File("D:\\Selenium Learning\\input.xlsx");
                FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(src);
                XSSFWorkbook wb=new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
                XSSFSheet ws=wb.getSheet("Sheet2");

                System.out.println("excel read successfully");

                ws.getRow(0).createCell(0).setCellValue("test");

                FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(src);
                wb.write(fos);
                wb.close();


            }

        }
```

after running code

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Wrong usage of method **instead of getRow** you have to **use createRow**

```
ws.createRow(0).createCell(0).setCellValue("test");
```

This will write string "test" to row 0 and column 0